# Does it make sense to do feature selection after PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a dataset of 50 features that resulted after PCA was employed (originally, the dataset had 343 features. The 50 features are the principal components obtained with PCA). Does it make sense to apply feature selection on those 50 features to choose the top 10 features?

Thank you,

Comment: Just to make sure, the original dataset had 50 features (PCA does not change the number of features, just the content thereof)?

Comment: No, the dataset originally had 343 features. I will revise my post.

Comment: How did you determine the number of PCs to keep, i.e. why 50?

Comment: @RichardHardy For security reasons, the dataset was given to me after being PCA transformed into 50 features which are the principal components obtained with PCA.

Comment: Then it can make sense to apply feature selection. But why 10? Is that a magic number?

Comment: @RichardHardy Honestly no. This is just an arbitrary number I will start with to investigate the performance of my model. My main concern was the invalidity of applying feature selection on the principal components obtained with PCA

Comment: Feature selection has already been done (50 from 343), so that question is out of the way. In any case, feature selection after PCA is very common. Often times this is the main motivation for the use of PCA.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it may very well make sense to do feature selection after PCA. PCA often yields a small number of components that explain a large fraction of variance in the data. Discarding the low-variance components and keeping only the high-variance components for future analysis can offer good a good balance w.r.t. the bias-variance tradeoff. In fact, PCA is often used precisely for that.